# CPU clock usage all of a sudden increased by a thousand. Should I be worried

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I have had this pc for less then a year. It's a CPU I5 9400F that uses 2900MHz, just yesterday or the day before, as I was doing a lot of stuff to fix the kernel id 41 problem. My CPU all of a sudden is beginning to use 3900MHz to 4000Mhz and this seems to be permanent. The information am getting this from is from this program called NZXT that tracks your CPU and other hardware. Should I be worried about this and try to do something? The last thing i remember doing was updating all my drivers  and troubleshooting my power.

Comment: Actually not entirely unexpected because the maximum Turbo Boost frequency of your CPU is 4.1 GHz. Hows your CPU load?

Comment: What exactly is your worry? Your CPU is running at the frequency it was designed to run at.  It’s not like it’s a limited resource. I strongly disagree with the answer below. “Should I be worried about this and try to do something?” - Since you were troubleshooting your power if sounds like you actually resolved a power issue that was resulting in reduced system performance. Your CPU running at 4 GHz isn’t a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be worried - you probably installed some software that
is wrong for your computer.
Drivers don't need to be updated generally by anybody except Microsoft.

I suggest, if System Restore is enabled, to rollback Windows to
before you did all these doubtful operations.

If System Restore is disabled, go into Device Manager, right-click
each device that you updated and select Properties, then Driver tab,
and click the Roll Back Driver button (not necessary if the
button is disabled).

The software you used to update the drivers might also have an
Undo option (if you're lucky).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > System > Power and Sleep > Additional power settings (on the right).

Then check if "balanced" is still selected. If not - change it back to balanced. (I've had that change by itself and got 100% CPU usage.)

If it *is* still "balanced", it might have changed internally so click on it > Change advanced power settings > scroll down to processor power management > minimum processor state.

Make sure it's something like 5%, *not* 100%.

(This is *a possible* solution. The problem might be something else, of course.)

**EDIT**

I disagree with the comment someone posted to your question telling you not to do anything about it. They might have missed this part in your question:

> and this seems to be permanent.

Comment: The CPU running at 4Ghz is different than utilization of 100%, you can’t use a CPUs frequency, you can saturate the CPU but that doesn’t use the CPUs frequency. A CPU can run at 4.0 GHz but the usage percentage can be low.